# woocommerce get API for order products store name

Tags: api, woocommerce

I'm creating a `API` for show order details. I need to show product `store name`. like this

[image]

This is my code:

```
include "auth.php";
$id= $_GET["id"]; // order_id
$result =  $woocommerce->get('orders/'.$id);
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

> Note: I want to get `store name` by `order_id`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, WooCommerce doesn't store the name of the store anywhere officially.
You could pull the name of the website, or add a settings field where users can enter the official store name.

To add a settings field, see:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adding-a-section-to-a-settings-tab/